# AD9553 PLL (Failure to Synchronize lock)

Tags: pll

I have been using the Analog Devices AD9553 Eval Board, I am operating it as a clock translator, inserting a 10MHz LVDS differential signal and setting the device to produce a 100MHz LVPECL differential signal. I aim to operate the device in the LBW region (B=0.17KHz) as my signal is not expected to deviate in frequency by drastic amounts.

At first I had issues with phase locking all together, but this was remedied (so may it seem). I can observe the lock signal remain high for the majority of the time, dropping low rarely.

However my main concern is that my system is supposedly locked - my 100MHz LVPECL signal does not stay stationary on the oscilloscope when triggered from the sinusoidal 10MHz reference signal. I am observing the sinusoidal reference signal as I cannot probe the LVDS signals when connected to the PLL (my scope only has 1M and 50R termination modes and this interferes - Scope:TDS5104B). I know there is **not** a problem with the LVDS conversion stage as all those signals are stationary on the scope.

I have had a play around with the values in the registers but to no avail (N Div etc). I have attempted to use the debug mode to view the PFD signals etc from the LOCK pin but they show nothing on the scope, the only one I can observe is the XTAL clock. I take it that because there are no signals on the PFD div 2, PFD ref div 2 and the PLL feedback div 2 - that there is a problem with my reference signal, values or the device.

Regarding my setup, I am prototyping the system on breadboard, I do not know if this could be a cause of problems (I have kept the wire lengths as small as possible and have a COAX going from the breadboard to the EVAL board) , but I am confused as it says the PLL is locked - but is infact not locked to its reference source. Attached is one of the combinations I tried from the EVAL board wizard software.
AD9553 Datasheet: http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9553.pdf

Guidance & Advice would be very much appreciated.

Thank you for reading this.

[image: Combinations in the EVAL software]

Comment: 100MHz on a breadboard is definitely asking for problems.

Comment: :\ , well the 10MHz LVDS is generated on the breadboard and is transferred with COAX to the EVAL board - this has SMA outputs which I am connecting directly to the scope. So 100MHz does not pass through the breadboard. However there is some ringing on the the 10MHz signal - dont know if that could be the cause of this?

Comment: Now that's a good question, worth looking into.

Comment: If the issue is with ringing (or some other issue) on the input, changing the bandwidth of the phase / frequency detector may show interesting results.

Comment: Yes I have changed the bandwidth of the frequency detector to the next stage (20KHz). The PLL lock indicator is now high permanently. However the LVPECL signals are still not stationary on the scope when triggered with the 10MHz sine wave.

Comment: With regards to the potential problems of a noisy power supply, I am currently running the system from a Bench PSU, generating 24v, this is broken down into 24,5 and 3.3 for use in the entire system. The regulators in use are switch mode buck converters, I have viewed the voltage characteristics on the scope and it does not seem too detrimental (similar performance to Linear Reg). The noise levels are about the same - however looking closely and probing my ground rail I can still see +- 300mV of noise. It was far greater before, as I had a ground loop problem; but I since rectified that.

Comment: I am also concerned that the PFD or the VCO is damaged since it is giving no observable signal in debug mode.

Comment: I usually trust lock indicators from monolithic devices, so this is very interesting. Is there a specific rate between the reference and output? That may shed some light.

Comment: What do you mean by specific rate? - Apologies however I failed to attach the image showing the register setup, it is now attached please see above.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this was to make sure the PLL is configured to accept a differential signal ! There is a register which allows this to be toggled.

Additionally the input amplitude of the 10 Meg LVDS needed to be attenuated to be accepted by the PLL, this was done via a 100R resistor across the two differential inputs.